# How to Create Controller and Views with diffrent name Grails scaffolding

Tags: grails, scaffolding, grails-controller

How to change the grails template file to add Prefix to the name of the controller and view package.
suppose i have User Domain, while using command create-scaffold-controller User should create AdminUserController.groovy and similarly create adminUser package for views instead of default UserCOntroller and respective views

Answer (score 0):

Install the templates on the project with grails install-templates and change the name on src/templates/scaffolding/Controller.groovy:

```
Example:
class Admin${className}Controller {
```

and the package name you can control on the create-scaffold-controller:

```
From the docs:
grails create-scaffold-controller org.bookstore.Book
```

or change directly in the template with variables:

```
<%=package org.admin.${className}%>
```

instead of:

```
<%=packageName ? "package ${packageName}\n\n" : ''%>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the command 'grails install-templates' and after, change the controller template in /src/template.